# Strange MediaPlayer behavior after reconnection

Tags: android, http, android-mediaplayer

I use own local server as data source for Android MediaPlayer object. When the player connects to the server in first time he sent GET request like this:

```
GET/ HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:53087
User-Agent: stagefright/1.1 (Linux;Android 3.2.1)
```

After for reconnection I recreate the player, but on connection he sends some another request:

```
GET HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:53087
Accept: */*
```

and drops the connection when takes a data immediately. After he sent a request as in the first time and starts playing.

Whats is the reason for so strange behavior?